# Text is not wrapping around image box

Tags: html, css

I have been stuck on getting the text to wrap around a div element that will contain an image. Right now, I'm just getting two columns rather than the text wrapping around the image.

https://codepen.io/kiggs1881/pen/KKZWwBw

```css
.main-box {
  border: solid green;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sub {
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.img-box {
  border: solid green;
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
  <div class="sub">
    orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
    vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent
    <span class="img-box">
        THIS IS TEXT
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You set the display to `flex`, which can be made to wrap but flex-elements won't "wrap around" each other. What do you want to happen, exactly? And the text you seem to want to wrap is enclosed in it's own box, your HTML structure doesn't really match what little I can comprehend of your intent.

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction. I removed the flex display, and then moved the img-box above the text. If you would like to post an answer, I could mark yours to close this.

Comment: How exactly do you want the text to be wrapped around the image